# Angular Empty Server Response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am using a factory in angular 1.6 that calls a GET request to a Rails 5 server. Inside the factory there is an $http call:

```
  $http({method: 'GET', url: urlString, params: dataToSend})
  .then(function successCallback(response) {
       console.log('in response');
       console.log(response);
  })

  return $http({method: 'GET', url: urlString, params: dataToSend});
```

This works with a maximum 7k rows returned from the server. As soon as it crosses a certain threshold (about 8k rows) the .data in the response becomes blank:

```
Object {data: "", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK", headers: function}
```

and there are no errors on the server logs.

As soon I put a limit into the server code.. in example limit to 5,000 rows, the .data is populated as needed.

Comment: I'm kind of lost on where to look into. So if anyone has some advice on where I can look, it would be really appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Bizarre answer.. the response data had some \n characters in it. Taking those out resolved the issue.